# Difference between "character*10 :: a" and "character :: a(10)"

Tags: arrays, syntax, fortran

Trying to refresh my Fortran 90 knowledge for a project, I have run into some oddity when using internal files. Consider the example code:

```
! ---- internal_file_confusion.f90 ----
program internal_file_confusion
  implicit none 

  character*40 :: string1
  character :: string2(40)

  write(string1, *) "Hello World 1"
  write(*,*) "string1 = ", string1

  write(string2, *) "Hello World 2"
  write(*,*) "string2 = ", string2

end program
```

which when compiled with `gfortran` crashes, writing to STDOUT

```
 string1 =  Hello World 1                          
At line 10 of file e:/Daten/tmp/fortran-training/internal_file_confusion.f90
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

When declared with the `*length` notation the character array can be used for internal write, but not when declared with the `name(length)` notation. Furthermore I noticed that the `*length` notation seems to be allowed only for character arrays, while it is forbidden with an error message like

```
Error: Old-style type declaration INTEGER*40 not supported at (1)
```

for other data types.

What is the difference between these notations and why does it affect use as internal files?

Comment: Use the tag [tag:fortran] , use the version only for version specific questions and only as an addition. Your question is valid even for later versions (90 is quite old).

Comment: Stackoverflow is like facebook. You come across your own post years later and feel weird looking at your younger, less knowledgeable self.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`character*40 :: string` is a character string of length 40

`character :: string*40` is the same

`character(len=40) :: string` is also a character string of length 40

`character :: string(40)` is an array of 40 character strings of length 1

`character*40 :: string(40)` is an array of 40 character strings of length 40

`character :: string(40)*40` is the same

`character(len=40) :: string(40)` is an array of 40 character strings of length 40

Your second internal writes fails, because it writes to the first string in the array `string2`. The first string `string2(1)` is just 1 character long and that is too short. For that reason you get the *end of record* error condition, the message is too long for the supplied string.

Internal writes treat array elements as separate records (similar to separate lines). One can utilize arrays of string in internal writes if one has more records (lines) to write into the array.