# Get size of array in uninstantiated user-defined data type

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Say the following module is given to me, and I am not allowed to edit it:

```
module somemod
  type somestruct
    character(40) somestr
  end type
end module
```

And I use it in this code:

```
program myprog
  use somemod

  implicit none

  character(size(somestruct%somestr)) localstr   !Is this possible?
end program
```

Is there syntax accomplish what the marked line is trying to do?  That is, can I get the size of an array in an user-defined data structure without instantiating the data structure?

Comment: There is no array in sight.  Do you mean the length of the character component?  [Which can be accomplished with the `len` function - but again on an object of that type.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
character(40) somestr
```

is not an array, it is a character string of length 40.

The difference is substantial, it is not just nitpicking. You use arrays and strings differently. See [Difference between "character*10 :: a" and "character :: a(10)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415590/difference-between-character10-a-and-character-a10/33421150#33421150) for more.

The length of a string is inquired by the intrinsic function `len()`.

But unfortunately, you cannot call it on a component of a derived type, without first having a variable (instance) of that type.

So you need

```
program myprog
  use somemod

  implicit none

  type(somestruct) :: o
  character(len(o%somestr)) localstr   !This is possible.
end program
```

If you needed the size of an array component, it would be the same, but with the `size()` intrinsic function.