# Character declaration forms

Tags: fortran, character

What is the meaning of the following character declaration

```
character :: c*4
```

Is it in anyway special for characters or does it apply to all data types?

Is the 4 the same as the length parameter as in

```
character(len=4) :: c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to declare the length of a character entity in a type declaration statement, but explanations of these are spread across several other questions and answers, so let's gather them here.  The forms of the question have the same effect.

A character declaration statement may specify the length in the type specifier using the `len=` form:

```
character(len=4) :: ...    ! Literal constant length
character(len=n) :: ...    ! Named constant/variable length
character(len=*) :: ...    ! Assumed/implied length
character(len=:) :: ...    ! Deferred length
```

or with the `*` form:

```
character*4   :: ...    ! Literal constant length
character*(4) :: ...    ! Another literal constant length
character*(n) :: ...    ! Named constant/variable length
character*(*) :: ...    ! Assumed/implied length
character*(:) :: ...    ! Deferred length
```

For the case of a literal constant, the parentheses are optional and not necessary, but are necessary for other cases.

Alternatively, the `*` form may be used in the entity declaration itself:

```
character :: a*4, b*(n), c*(*), d*(:)
character(len=2) :: x*4   ! The *4 overrides the len=2
```

In all cases, `1` is the default length if no value is specified.

If you want to specify length and array shape in this way:

```
character :: a(5,5)*4
character(len=2), dimension(2) :: b(5,5)*4  ! Shape and length overridden.
```

The form of specification using `*` is unique to character lengths (for functions and variables). Even non-character objects with length type parameters cannot use this syntax. However, as Vladimir F notes, there is the similar non-standard form like `integer*4`.

Finally, the `name*(len)` form is specific to type declaration statements. It can't be used, for example, in allocation:

```
character(:), allocatable :: c

allocate(character :: c*4)      ! Not allowed as length specification, use instead
allocate(character(len=4) :: c) ! or
allocate(character*4 :: c)      ! etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both strings of the same length. See also [Difference between “character*10 :: a” and “character :: a(10)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415590/difference-between-character10-a-and-character-a10/33421150#33421150).

The syntax is completely special for characters and cannot be used for other datatypes. Re-using the syntax for other datatypes like `integer*4` might be motivated by the old Hollerith editing, where characters were stored in integer numbers, but is completely non-standard.